# list indices must be integers, not list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of random numbers.
I want to know if a number in that list is in another list.

For some reason It's telling me "list indices must be integers, not list"

I know that an int is not the same as an int in a list. I'm just not sure how I go about seeing if they are the same or not.

An example of how to compare an int to a number in a list would be very much appreciated.
I have looked through here and on different websites and none of the examples I've run across help me; that, or I just don't understand their solution.

Thanks again.

Edit:

Here is my code with the "number in list" part, but it still comes up with the same error.

```
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):  #goes through the list of numbers
    for j in (i, range(len(a))):    #checks if the first numbers appears again
        for q in (0, range(len(b))):  #checks if that number is in the 
            if (a[i] == a[j] and a[i] in b == true):  #the second list 
                b.append(a[i])
            else:
                continue
return b
```

I'm getting my error at the first `if` Statement

Edit 2:
`import random 
a = [ random.randrange(20) for _ in range(20) ]`

so a is a list of random integers

I have a function called unique and I call `unique(a)`

This the the exact error I get:

import random

a = [ random.randrange(20) for _ in range(20) ]

unique(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "a5.py", line 8, in unique

```
if (a[i] == a[j] and temp in b == true):
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: Show us your code, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out whether a number is in a list of numbers, just do this:

```
>>> list_of_numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> number = 20
>>> number in list_of_numbers
True
```

If you want to know *where* in the list it is, use `index`:

```
>>> list_of_numbers.index(number)
1
>>> list_of_numbers[1]
20
```

If you want to know *all* the places it appears in the list, you will have to write an explicit loop statement or comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_numbers = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
>>> [index for index, element in list_of_numbers if element == number]
1, 5
```

If you want to know whether any of the numbers in one list are also in another, do this:

```
>>> other_list = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
>>> set(other_list).intersection(list_of_numbers)
{10}
```

If you want to know how many of the numbers in one list are in another:

```
>>> other_list = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
>>> len(set(other_list).intersection(list_of_numbers))
1
```

If you want to know if the number 23 appears in every list you have, you need to take either less heroin (if you == 'William S. Burroughs') or fewer bad film roles (if you == 'Jim Carrey').

Comment: I tried the number in list, it still didn't work

Comment: @Gabriel, we can't see what you tried, you have to post it to your question. And say what “didn't work” means.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm sorry guys, the answer was right in this original answer. I just didn't understand it the fist time I read it. Thank you abarnert. Very much appreciated.